# FFmpeg - blurry or transparent outlines

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm merging a bunch of videos into one and I'm looking for a specific effect / technique to add to a each of those videos. But I don't exactly know what that effect is called and how to achive it by ffmpeg.

I would describe the outcome as a video with 3 columns . In the center you got the actual video and left and right there's a blurry version of that same video.

Is something like this possible with `ffmpeg` ?

Example :
[image]

Comment: Thank Gyan ! Boxblur was the keyword I was looking for. Here's the command from the linked answer : ffmpeg -i video720x1280.mp4
  -filter_complex
      "[0]scale=hd1080,setsar=1,boxblur=20:20[b];
       [0]scale=-1:1080[v];[b][v]overlay=(W-w)/2"   video1920x1080.mp4